# gulp task to concat javascript, if files available in a folder, else get them from elsewhere

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, gulp, concatenation

For the simplicity of explanation let's imagine this folder structure:`

```
base
   - folder-a
      - script.js
   - folder-b
      - script.js
   - folder-c
      - script.js

custom
   - folder-a
      - script.js
   - folder-b
```

I have a gulp task to concat all `script.js` of all folders in the `base/folders`.

```
gulp.task('componentsJs', function() {
    return  gulp.src('./components/**/*.js')
            .pipe(concat('components-min.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/min'))
            .pipe(rename( {
                basename: "components",
                suffix: '-min'
            }))
            //.pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/min/'))
            .pipe(notify({ message: 'Components scripts task complete',  onLast: true }));
 });
```

So here's what I would like to do: having a task that concats all script.js for each `custom/folders`, if there's a `script.js` file within the `custom/folder`, it should use this script (eg. `custom/folder-a/scripts.js` ) if there's no `script.js` (eg. `custom/folder-b/` ) the script.js wasn't customised and therefore it should fallback on `base/folder-b/script.js`

Requirements are the following:

- There should be any foldername for subfolders (eg `folder-a`)
- if in custom a folder not exists, its `script.js` should be ignored

I've tried to make an if statement I've found on stackoverflow as this:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    files = ['src/js/**/*.js'],
    extraFile = 'path/to/other/file';

if( fs.existsSync(extraFile)) {
    files.push(extraFile);
} else {
  console.log('FILE DOES NOT EXIST');
}
```

Anyone suggestions on this?